# Date formatting issue in java

Tags: java

When I parsing time in java, I passing "12:12" as string argument, then I am getting **"Thu Jan 01 12:12:00 IST 1970"** as a output.

I want current year like **"Fri Mar 09 12:12:00 IST 2012"** as a output.

```
String timestr = "12:12";
Date convertedDate = null;
try {
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
  convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(timestr);
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(convertedDate);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the problem with this is that you are creating a date with null values and then just initialize the time value. I think you should use the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class and get an instance of the Calendar and then set the time. Once that is done, you create a date object from the Calendar and parse it to your needs.